# Сломался код на Python библиотеки gdown

Tags: python, google-drive

В общем есть у меня код, который скачивает библиотекой gdown файлы с Google диска на мой компьютер, а далее я работаю с ними в остальном коде.
Проблема такая: У меня всё неделю назад работало, а теперь код ничего не скачивает :( Причем, на PythonAnyWhere, куда я заливал бота на какое-то время - все по прежнему работает как часы, а у меня на компьютере (или у других людей) - не работает. Ссылки если что рабочие, как и раньше.
Пробовал: Откатывать Python, библиотеки, даже пробовал скачать все содержимое с PythonAnyWhere и запускать в этой среде...
Помогите пожалуйста а то я в программировании нубчик

Мой код:

```
# Загружаем планшетки
url1 = data['link1']  # Загрузчик первой
output1 = gdown.download(url1, None, quiet=False) # Стокове название с диска
gdown.download(url1, output1, quiet=False)

url2 = data['link2'] # Загрузчик второй
output2 = gdown.download(url2, None, quiet=False) # Стокове название с диска
gdown.download(url2, output2, quiet=False)
```

Моя ошибка при запуске:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\project\planshetka.py", line 32, in <module>
    output1 = gdown.download(url1, None, quiet=False) # Стокове название с диска
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\gdown\download.py", line 259, in download
    filename_from_url = m.groups()[0]
                        ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: А какая версия питона на PythonAnyWhere, может там более старая?

Comment: Я пытался поставить более старый Python, но дело в том, что это не помогло. Более того раньше все и на моем компьютере работало (то есть я ничего не менял неделю, решил снова заняться проектом - а он не работает в этом моменте)

Comment: В интернетах советуют откатить версию gdown, попробуйте: pip install gdown==4.7.0